# How to get file content with a proper utf-8 encoding using file_get_contents?

Tags: php, utf-8, file-get-contents

I need to get content of the remote file in utf-8 encoding. The file in in utf-8. When I display that file on screen, it has proper encoding:

http://www.parfumeriafox.sk/source_file.html

(notice the `ň` and `č` characters, for example, these are alright).

When I run this code:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://parfumeriafox.sk/source_file.html';

$csv = file_get_contents_utf8($url);
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
print $csv;

function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) {
  $content = file_get_contents($fn);
  return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'utf-8');
}
```

(you can run it using http://www.parfumeriafox.sk/encoding.php), then I get question marks instead of those special characters. I have done huge research on this, I have tried standard `file_read_contents` function, I have even used some stream bla bla php context function, I also tried fopen and fread function to read that file on binary level, nothing seems to work. I have tried that with and without sending header. This is supposed to be perfectly siple, what am I doing wrong? When I check that string with some encoding detect function, it returns `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How about this one????**

For this one I used `header('Content-Type: text/plain;; charset=Windows-1250');`

bergamot, citrón, tráva, rebarbora, bazalka;levanduľa, škorica, hruška;céderové drevo, vanilka, pižmo, amberlyn

---

[image]

---

**This code works for me**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=Windows-1250');
echo file_get_contents('http://www.parfumeriafox.sk/source_file.html');
?>
```

---

The problem is not with file_get_contents()

I save the $data to a file and the characters were correct but still not encoded correctly by my text editor.  See image below.

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.parfumeriafox.sk/source_file.html');
file_put_contents('doc.txt',$data);
```

### UPDATE

**Seems to be one problematic character as shown here.**
It also is seen on the HTML image below.  Renders as ¾

Its Hex value is xBE (190 decimal)

I tried these two character sets.  Neither worked.

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO 8859-1');
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO 8859-2');
```

---

[image]

---

**END OF UPDATE**

---

It works by adding a header WITHOUT charset=utf-8.

These two headers work

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Type: text/html');
```

These two headers do NOT work

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

This code is tested and displayed all characters.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo file_get_contents('http://www.parfumeriafox.sk/source_file.html');
?>
```

[image]

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html');
echo file_get_contents('http://www.parfumeriafox.sk/source_file.html');
?>
```

[image]

---

These are some of the problematic characters with their Hex values.
This is the saved file viewed in Notepad++ with UTF-8 Encoding.

[image]

Check the Hex values against these character sets.

[image]

From the above table I saw the character set was Latin2.

I went to [Wikipedia Windows code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page)  and found that Latin2 is Windows-1250

---

bergamot, citrón, tráva, rebarbora, bazalka;levanduľa, škorica, hruška;céderové drevo, vanilka, pižmo, amberlyn

Comment: No, it does not, I can see "è" where it should read "č", "ò" instead of "ň", etc...

Comment: I would not catch those.  I was able to find the one character.  Well it improved.  I found the on character after I posted.  You need to know what character encoding is being used then add that character set to the header().  This link might help:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96529/ch2.htm

Comment: I do not believe the problem is with file_get_contents(), I updated my post with more info.

Comment: Thanks, nice research. It works now with the Windows encoding, which is funny because the party which sends the file keep saying it's in UTF-8 encoding, which probably is not. Anyway, where did I tell there was a problem with the file_get_contents() functions?

Answer (score 3):

You can see which character set your browser decided the document was by opening the developer console and looking at `document.characterSet`:

```
> document.characterSet
"windows-1250"
```

With this knowledge we can ask iconv to convert from "windows-1250" to utf-8 for us:

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents("source_file.csv");
$text = iconv("windows-1250", "utf-8", $text);
print($text);
```

The output is valid utf-8, and levanduľa is displayed correctly as well.